# Checking for substring from a frame A in a different Frame B, with different sizes for each frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I do have a question hoping - I am confindet that you can help me out. Suppose I do have two frames, each having multiple columns, but for simplicity let's focus on one column per frame.
**Important**: **Both frame are different in size, with A being shorter**

```
import pandas as pd

FrameA=pd.DataFrame({"A":["00281378554", "10862520000","82540193700","76015394900","00134355050","21864009"]})

FrameB=pd.DataFrame({"A":["AT511634000134355050","AT411513000281378554", "AT711509100151013992",
"AT511509000121340020","AT424480010862520000","AT742011182540193700","AT531200076015394900","HU02142201082186400900000000"
]})
```

My goal is following: I want to check for each element of column A from frameA if **it is contained** in Col A from Frame B, if so then I want create a new column in frame A (shorter dimension) with following outcome:

```
Frame A
Col A            Col B
00281378554      AT411513000281378554
10862520000      AT424480010862520000
82540193700      AT742011182540193700
76015394900      AT531200076015394900
00134355050      AT511634000134355050
21864009         HU02142201082186400900000000
```

So the new column B for frameA shall contain the element from frameB which contains the string from frame A
I tried with `np.where` but as frameA is shorter in dimension than frameB it is not working. So all I could do is use a for loop. But this is extremely time-consuming and I do think there must be a more elegant solution

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the substring always in the end and always with the same length?

Comment: always at the end but not same size. We are dealing with IBAN data and bank account. column A from frame A is containing bank accounts while column A from frame B contains IBANS and Ibans contain bank accounts

Comment: OK then I have a workaround to suggest, but please update your example ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the substring in FrameA is always matching the last 11 characters in FrameB, then slice and [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
FrameA['B'] = FrameA['A'].map(FrameB.set_index(FrameB['A'].str[-11:])['A'])
```

Or with [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
out = FrameA.merge(FrameB.rename(columns={'A': 'B'}),
                   left_on='A', right_on=FrameB['A'].str[-11:], how='left')
```

Output:

```
             A                     B
0  00281378554  AT411513000281378554
1  10862520000  AT424480010862520000
2  82540193700  AT742011182540193700
3  76015394900  AT531200076015394900
4  00134355050                   NaN
```

---

If the substring is not fixed, you can form groups of the same length and use the same approach. You could also ensure that FrameB doesn't contain duplicated values

```
def make_mapper(length):
    idx = FrameB['A'].str[-length:]
    return (FrameB.set_index(idx)['A']
            .groupby(level=0).first()
           )

FrameA['B'] = (FrameA.groupby(FrameA['A'].str.len(), group_keys=False)['A']
                     .apply(lambda g: g.map(make_mapper(g.name)))
              )
```

Output:

```
             A                     B
0  00281378554  AT411513000281378554
1  10862520000  AT424480010862520000
2  82540193700  AT742011182540193700
3  76015394900  AT531200076015394900
4  00134355050                   NaN
```

After this first (efficient) mapping step, you can use a second, less efficient, logic to fill map the other values based on a substring anywhere:

```
def find_anywhere(substr):
    return next((s for s in FrameB['A'] if substr in s), None)

m = FrameA['B'].isna()
FrameA.loc[m, 'B'] = FrameA.loc[m, 'A'].map(find_anywhere)
```

Final output:

```
             A                             B
0  00281378554          AT411513000281378554
1  10862520000          AT424480010862520000
2  82540193700          AT742011182540193700
3  76015394900          AT531200076015394900
4  00134355050          AT511634000134355050
5     21864009  HU02142201082186400900000000
```

Comment: What if we use instead `[-11:]` [2:]? The first two digits are always a country code :=)

Comment: @SMS because there are extra digits in between: `AT-4115130-00281378554`, but sure, you can also slice from the left if this makes sense ;)

Comment: I get the following error: "Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects"
Any suggestions?

Comment: @SMS please try my second solution, it should handle multiple lengths and avoid duplicates (it keeps the first match in case of duplicates). But please, update your question with a representative example.

Comment: Really amazing and almost. I have here a special case:

3930138 --> DE63750700130393013800
I cannot find this with your proposal. Any suggestion how to make it more flexible?

Comment: I updated my example from above which leaves a blank cell if I apply your code.
Any suggestion regarding this challenge?

Comment: @SMS There is no `AT511634000134355050` in FrameB, where is it coming from? Also `21864009` is not matching in the end of `HU02142201082186400900000000`, so this would required a much less efficient logic

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257264/discussion-between-sms-and-mozway).

Comment: @SMS see update. I suggest to use 2 pass, one to map efficiently the values from the end, then a second one to check the missing rows

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, which uses `regex` to find the matches, and  `list comprehension`:

```
import re

pd.DataFrame(
    [[x, y] for x in FrameA.A for y in FrameB.A if re.match(f'.*{x}.*',y)],
    columns=list('AB'))
```

Output:

```
             A                             B
0  00281378554          AT411513000281378554
1  10862520000          AT424480010862520000
2  82540193700          AT742011182540193700
3  76015394900          AT531200076015394900
4  00134355050          AT511634000134355050
5     21864009  HU02142201082186400900000000
```

Answer (score 0):

By using this you don't need to worry about matching length:

```
FrameA['B'] = FrameA['A'].apply(lambda x: FrameB.loc[FrameB['A'].str.contains(x), 'A'].iloc[0] if not FrameB.loc[FrameB['A'].str.contains(x), 'A'].empty else None)
```

Comment: You have to keep in mind that this is quadratic, for n rows you'll test n**2 rows. IF really such a search is needed, you should really not use `apply` + `loc`, that would be terribly slow.

Comment: Fully agree, it is quite slow and not faster than my for loop